# How can I stop a root password from triggering a change entry in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

When ever I run my ansible playbook I always get,

```
TASK [set password] ****************************************************************
changed: [10.1.38.15]
```

As an entry in the log. I don't want that to show, as the password was already set. Is there a way for ansible to track to easily track this?

My play is

```
- name: set password                                                            
  run_once: true                                                                
  user:                                                                         
    name: root                                                                  
    password: "{{ 'bleh' | password_hash('sha512') }}"                      
    expires: -1
```

I even tried `run_once` which I saw others mention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed what should happen. However, you do not pass the same encrypted password every time: `password_hash` can take a salt as a second parameter. If absent, one is generated randomly.
(Salt is used to protect against pre-computed dictionary attacks, so the hash value for `bleh` will be different every time)

Compare:

```
ansible all -i localhost, -m debug -a "msg={{ 'mypassword' | password_hash('sha256') }}"
```

run several times, with result changing, with

```
ansible all -i localhost, -m debug -a "msg={{ 'mypassword' | password_hash('sha512', 'mysecretsalt') }}"
```

where the result stays the same because you fix the salt.

Comment: that works, thanks

Comment: That took a minute to sink in to my brain. While you are technically not changing the password, you ARE making a change every time (without the predefined salt), because ansible is writing a new hashed value (of the same password) into the shadow file. Wow. /insert head explode emoji